# How to remove Russian boxes in Sci-hub?

Tags: ads

After being accessed to the research paper I need via [Sci-hub](http://sci-hub.io), there are multiple Russian boxes show in the screen. How can I eliminate them? I have tried to disable JavaScript, but the PDF file cannot load.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm all for sci-hub and I don't really mind extra boxes asking e.g. for donations, but I really don't see the point of annoying boxes that don't adapt to non-Russian speakers (and also top bars that don't scroll away.

To programmatically do away with those boxes, you can use the following userscript. I use it on Tampermonkey over Google Chrome, but you can probably also use it on Greasemonkey and other platforms. The key things to do are to make the divs diwth IDs `#save`, `#reload`, `#donate` and `#donatein` go away, and to reset the `#content` div's `top` css attribute to zero.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Remove annoying divs
// @include  http://sci-hub.cc/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

/*--- Use the jQuery contains selector to find content to remove.
    Beware that not all whitespace is as it appears.
*/

function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}

var badDivs = $( "#save, #reload, #donate, #donatein");

addGlobalStyle('#content { top: 0px !important; }');

badDivs.remove ();

//-- Or use badDivs.hide(); to just hide the content.
```

Comment: I publish this in GreasyFork, and will maintain if Sci-Hub changes: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/28331-remove-annoying-boxes-from-sci-hub

Answer (score 1):

Simple
Just like a check this [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com.sci-hub.io/science/article/pii/0038071794901317) and a pdf appear, having 8 pages.
Then it shows same Russian options at sides and at top.
If you want to remove those then got to

> INSPECT ELEMENT(Q)

option of your browser after right click on that box
It will show a html tag inside a `<div........>` tag

> Remove that DIV tag by PRESSING delete button

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to automate that?

Comment: Actually it is generated on each page, so have to remove them manually or download that pdf